# Securing java runtime data on an untrusted client

Tags: java, security, encryption

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but is it feasible to secure, end-to-end runtime data on an uncontrolled client?

Specifically, is there any functionality in Java to take in encrypted data, process it and send it back out encrypted, all without exposing the data in plaintext to a curious 3rd party that has full access to the client?

Also, I know that code obfuscation is merely an annoyance to a dedicated individual with a decompiler, so I'm assuming for this scenario that the attack party has full source/operating knowledge.

I'm interested in answers either way. If there is no existing functionality, would it be feasible given Java's architecture? If Java can't do it, is there another language/platform that could? I'm fearing this may require special hardware.

Comment: It may be worth describing what you're trying to achieve, rather than focus on the implementation details.

Comment: So basically you want to implement DRM !

Comment: As dirty as that word is, yes essentially, that's what I'm looking to do. The goal however is not to control saleable content distribution, but to enable secure cloud computing features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a chance at doing what you are talking about, you need special hardware. You can't have a secure layer "on top" of an insecure layer. For example, if the attacker has full control over the hardware, he can always compromise the OS running on that host.

The special hardware is called a "Trusted Platform Module," or TPM. This supports remote attestation, which would allow you to verify that a client has not been tampered with. Some parts of the TPM are available on many computers (my Dell laptop, for example). In fact, I think all computers purchased by the US federal government are required to have a TPM. However, most consumers do not enable the TPM, and there's a lot of hostility toward TPM from privacy advocates. I'm also unsure how many machines with a TPM include the remote attestation capability.

Anyway, the bottom line is that you can't give someone a secret, and the key to the secret, and expect it to remain a secret. You have to retain control over the whole stack, top-to-bottom. <strike>Trusted</strike> Treacherous Computing allows you do do that, even if you don't legally own the hardware in question.

Comment: That's what I had a feeling would be needed. I found a TPM project for Java at http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/ but it is still in the "experimental" R&D phase.

Comment: Breaking news - someone has reportedly cracked a widely used Infineon TPM chip - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/02/17/infineon_tpm_crack/
Apparently it is not easy to do, but it proves that TPM is not a silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamentally not possible to be completely secure if the client is not locked down.  At some point the bytes will exist in memory, and that memory can be read by hostile applications.

If your goal isn't to make it completely secure but merely inconvenient for the casually curious, then just be sure to not write the data to temporary files or anywhere else that would be trivial to examine.

Answer (score 1):

Not only "can't be done", but "easy to compromise".

Look at 'aspect-oriented programming' and byte-compiler classes.  This is normally used for things like inserting database transactions, performance logging, logging statements (so you can drop the calls from the source code and make it a lot cleaner), access control (so you separate the implementation and authorization), etc.  There are a lot of extremely useful things you can do if you can quietly wrap one class with another.

But that also means it's trivial to wrap your classes to capture all of the unencrypted messages within your application, encryption keys, etc.  I think I can get in even if you do everything in a single long procedure, although it might take a little more effort.